# PL/SQL getting part of a node that isn't a leaf?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an XML file that I am trying to parse and process in PL/SQL. Everything has been solvable up to this point. I have a node where I need to get some information that isn't in the leaf.

```
<Division_Description Descriptor="00 Office">
    <ID>788758885</ID>
</Division_Description>
```

I need the value from "descriptor". I am using EXTRACTVALUE() to parse most of the nodes that I need. If I use

```
EXTRACT(Value(p),'/Division_Description').getStringVal() as v_DIVISON_DESCRIPTION,
```

I get the above little XML.

I tried using @descriptor at the end of the extract and extractvalue functions (as in extract(..., '.../Division_Description@Descriptor') but that resulted in an exception.

How do I get the Descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Try this:

```
/Division_Description/@Descriptor
```